# How to show only one object if there's multiple equal objects in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I am sorry for the title but this is the best way I can explain it.

I have a `trips` model that has `in_flights` and `out_flights` associated to a `Client`.

I wanted to show which `Clients` have trips after *now* so I did the following:

```
ClientsArriving = Client.objects.filter(trip__in_flight__date__gt=timezone.now())
ClientsLeaving = Client.objects.filter(trip__out_flight__date__gt=timezone.now()) 
ClientsDash = ClientsLeaving | ClientsArriving
```

The problem is, if one Client has an `in_flight` and an `out_flight` in the same `trip`, it will display twice.

How can I show the `trip` only one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the querysets togethers and add a `distinct`:

```py
ClientsDash = ( 
    Client.objects
    .filter(trip__in_flight__date__gt=timezone.now())
    .filter(trip__out_flight__date__gt=timezone.now())
    .distinct()
)
```

reference:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Comment: This is great, thanks! and thanks for the reference!